# Количество байт, которое занимает UTF8 символ в char * строке?

Tags: c, utf-8

Для итерации по словам строки в кодировке UTF8 мне понадобилось разобраться в том, как узнать по-первому байту символа общее количество его байт. Я только начинаю разбираться с UTF8, поэтому не совсем понимаю наверняка механику битовых операций, которая для этого используется (судя по большинству примеров в интернете).

---

На StackOverflow я нашёл два решения:

1) [Способ 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977644/598057)

```
size_t utf8_char_length(char firstbyte) {
    if ((firstbyte & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
        if ((firstbyte & 0xF0) == 0xF0) {
            return 4;
        } else if ((firstbyte & 0xE0) == 0xE0) {
            return 3;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

2) Второе решение найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7432073/598057), оно использует другой способ: вместо битовой операции & используется "lookup" по следующему массиву из 256 символов:

```
static const size_t utf8_skip_data[256] = {
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
    2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
    3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,1,1
};
```

---

К сожалению, я сейчас не имею возможности досконально разобраться с UTF8, поэтому просто ищу надёжную функцию, которая будет давать мне правильные результаты для символов в кодировке в UTF8 (точнее для первых байт этих символов). Мне больше нравится второе решение, но я хочу услышать мнение более опытных специалистов:

**какую функцию стоит использовать для такой задачи: 1, 2 или, может быть, вы знаете какую-то проверенную свою функцию, которая лучше, чем эти две?**

P.S. Кстати, если кто-то может объяснить, откуда взялась lookup-таблица, буду признателен. На SO пишут, что она взята из исходного кода `glib's gutf8.c`. Так вот интересно, какой принцип лежит в её основе.

Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не возиться с UTF-8 вообще. Сделайте так:

1. Файлы содержат информацию в UTF-8 (или другой кодировке). При чтении из них сразу перекодируйте в UCS-2 (wchar_t*) или если надо UCS-4, чтобы длина каждого символа была одинаковой.
2. Работайте только с информацией с символами постоянной байтовой длины.
3. При записи в файл перекодируйте назад в utf-8 или какая там кодировка нужна.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за совет. Всё-таки я хочу немного повозиться именно с UTF-8, чтобы посмотреть как работает итерация по словам (A-Za-zА-Яа-я) на лету, без преобразования кодировок.

Comment: > Прошу прощения, выражение 'lookup-таблица' сбило меня с толку и навеяло неверные ассоциации. Да, действительно, эта таблица предназначена для проверки первого байта последовательности и решения о длине кода. Лично я всё равно склоняюсь к функции - она выглядит гораздо лаконичнее. Но lookup-таблица работает быстрее, если это принципиально, лучше использовать её.

Спасибо, всё стало на свои места. Я некоторое время не приму ваш ответ как правильнй, вдруг кто-то ещё что-то ответит. Закрытые вопросы обычно не располагают к тому, чтобы в них что-то добавлять))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вкратце алгоритм кодирования символов в UTF8 выглядит так:

1. Если код символа меньше 128, то кодируется как есть.
2. Если больше или равно, то кодируется в следующем формате: в первом байте в единичном коде записывается количество использованных байт включая первый (то есть записывается такое число единиц, сколько байт в числе; теоретически формат UTF8 не накладывает ограничений на количество байт, используемых для записи числа, но обычно используется не более 6). Затем записывается 0 (чтобы отделить количество байт числа от значащих разрядов числа), после чего идут биты, представляющие число. Каждый следующий байт начинается с последовательности 10 (чтобы не путать однобайтные и многобайтные символы - все однобайтные начинаются с нуля).

Например,

**111** *0* 0011 *10* 011101 *10* 000100

1. Сначала **3 единицы**, значит, для записи используется 3 байта.
2. Затем *0*, отделяющий запись числа байт от записи числа
3. Дальше значащие разряды числа. Первые 2 бита каждого байта (*10*) к ним не относятся - это метки, означающие, что это второй (третий, и т. д.) байт записи.

Таким образом, записанный код - 0011011101000100. Это к вопросу о том, откуда взялась lookup-таблица. К вопросу какую функцию использовать - исходите из потребностей. Если вы всегда будете работать с символами, код которых не превышает 256, то используйте lookup-таблицу, она быстрее. Если же планируется полная поддержка Юникода, то используйте функцию. Только её придётся модифицировать, так как она не распознает 5- и 6-байтные символы.

**UPD**

Прошу прощения, выражение 'lookup-таблица' сбило меня с толку и навеяло неверные ассоциации. Да, действительно, эта таблица предназначена для проверки первого байта последовательности и решения о длине кода. Лично я всё равно склоняюсь к функции - она выглядит гораздо лаконичнее. Но lookup-таблица работает быстрее, если это принципиально, лучше использовать её.

Comment: > Если вы всегда будете работать с символами, код которых не превышает 256, то используйте lookup-таблицу, она быстрее. Если же планируется полная поддержка Юникода, то используйте функцию.

Спасибо за ответ. А почему вы считаете, что функция не работает с юникод символами? Она по-моему как раз и предназначена для этого, просто lookup же как раз и происходит __по первому байту__, разве нет? В той ссылке, как раз её используют для того, чтобы определить наперёд сколько байт 1, 2, ... или 6 скопировать.

Comment: Обратите внимание, приведённая вами функция возвращает только значения 1, 2, 3 и 4, поэтому определить 6-байтный символ она в принципе не может (она примет его за 4-байтный).

Comment: > Обратите внимание, приведённая вами функция возвращает только значения 1, 2, 3 и 4, поэтому определить 6-байтный символ она в принципе не может (она примет его за 4-байтный).

Это я прекрасно понимаю. В своём предыдущем комментарии я имею в виду исключительно способ с lookup-таблицей - меня интересует, почему вы указали, что я не могу её использовать для UTF8. Надеюсь, я правильно понял ваш ответ.

Comment: Нет, предложение о модификации относсилось к функции. Читать следует так:

> __(__ Если вы всегда будете работать с символами, код которых не превышает 256, то используйте lookup-таблицу, она быстрее. __)__
>__(__ Если же планируется полная поддержка Юникода, то используйте функцию. Только её придётся модифицировать, так как она не распознает 5- и 6-байтные символы. __)__

Comment: Теперь я понял, что сам создал недоразумение в первом комментарии. Мой первый комментарий относился на самом деле к lookup-таблице, вот я подставил вместо функции таблицу:

> Спасибо за ответ. А почему вы считаете, что __lookup-таблица__ не работает с юникод символами? Она по-моему как раз и предназначена для этого, просто lookup же как раз и происходит по первому байту, разве нет? В той ссылке как раз её используют для того, чтобы определить наперёд сколько байт 1, 2, ... или 6 скопировать.

P.S. С функцией utf8_char_length() всё ясно, интересно теперь уточнить про таблицу.

Comment: Lookup-таблица плоха тем, что в ней учтены только первые 256 символов. А в Юникоде из более 110000. Конечно, никто не мешает вам сделать lookup-таблицу на все символы весом в сотню килобайт (или в полсотни если записвать два числа в один байт), но это как-то убого смотрится.

Comment: Я осмелюсь предположить, что вы не совсем поняли, в чём состоит суть этой lookup-таблицы - она __не предназначена__ для того, чтобы смотреть все 110000 символов, - она нужна для того, чтобы смотреть __первые байты__ любого из этих 110000 символов и в соответствии с этими первыми байтами она  возвращает количество байт, которое занимает данный символ согласно спецификации UTF8. Разве нет?

Comment: Прошу прощения, выражение 'lookup-таблица' сбило меня с толку и навеяло неверные ассоциации. Да, действительно, эта таблица предназначена для проверки первого байта последовательности и решения о длине кода. Лично я всё равно склоняюсь к функции - она выглядит гораздо лаконичнее. Но lookup-таблица работает быстрее, если это принципиально, лучше использовать её.

P. S. Ещё я ошибся с количеством символов в Юникоде - их не 110000, а 1100000.