# Как определить, является ли UTF8 символ буквенным?

Tags: c, utf-8, unicode

Предположим, что у меня есть строка "привет" в кодировке UTF8. Эта строка находится в C-строке `char *str`.

Я хочу узнать, как мне определить, является ли, например, первый символ этой строки буквенным (A-Za-zА-Яа-я).

В своём другом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299862/utf-8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-utf8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-char-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5) я вроде бы прояснил, "как узнать, какое количество байт занимает UTF8 символ в char * строке", откуда следует простое ветвление:

1) если символ однобайтный - его просто можно проверить посредством

```
if ('A' <= currentByte && currentByte <= 'z') {}
```

2) если символ двубайтный - его нужно проверять на русские буквы - вот здесь и начинается вопрос: Я могу сделать каст этого 2-х байтного символ в 2-байтное число и сравнить его со всеми подряд 16-ричными кодами русского алфавита, которые известны.

3) если символ более чем 2-байтный - игнориуем этот случай, так как латинский+русский алфавит помещаются в 1+2 байтах в UTF8.

---

Что я не понимаю, это **как сделать проверку 16-ричного кода двубайтового символа на соответствие всем 16-ричным кодам русского алфавита быстрой и компактной?**

Буду признателен за помощь. Спасибо.

---

Вот моя наивная попытка:

```
const char *bytes = source.bytes; // Здесь лежит UTF-8 строка из двух символов - "ая";

for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    unsigned char currentByte = (unsigned char)bytes[i];

    size_t charLength = utf8_char_length[currentByte];

    if (charLength == 1) {
        printf("character %c %d\n", currentByte, currentByte);

        if ('A' <= currentByte && currentByte <= 'z') {
            printf("latin %c\n", currentByte);
        }
    } else if (charLength == 2) {
        unsigned short twobytesymbol = *(unsigned short *)(bytes + i);

        printf("(2 bytes) %X\n", twobytesymbol);

        i++;
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

Вывод:
(2 bytes) B0D0
(2 bytes) 8FD1
```

Я не понимаю, почему в [таблице кодов Unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024): коды букв "а" и "я" имеют 16-ричные коды перевёрнутые относительно моих:

"а": **d0 b0**, "я": **d1 8f**

Из-за этого я не могу по-человечески проверить весь диапазон русского алфавита. Подозреваю, что тут какая-то очевидность скрывается, которую я пока что не понимаю.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, если интересуют буквы какого-то конкретного языка (или семейства), то особых проблем нет. 

Большинство символов букв (например, кириллицы) занимают сплошной диапазон unicode.

Переводите utf-8 в ucs-32 и сравниваете на попадание (пердварительно оценив в таблице unicode интересующий Вас алфавит) в нужный диапазон (плюс ёЁ для чисто русского). 



Конечно, можно попробовать включить нужную локализацию (setlocale()) и проверять iswalpha(), но локализации не всегда настроены на конкретной машине.

Comment: @avp: А ещё äöüÄÖÜß для немецкого, âàéèêëîïôùûüÿçÂÀÉÈÊËÎÏÔÙÛÜŸÇ для французского, çğıöşÇĞİÖŞ для турецкого, ąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ для польского...

Comment: @VladD, насколько помню все эти latin-*123* тоже подряд идут (как и греческий). 

Там интересней с low/uppercase. Скажем, в кириллице сначала все uppercase, а потом lowcase, а в latin (если память не изменяет) четные коды low, а нечетные upper (или наоборот).

--

Пардон, напутал. Часть latin, как написал, а часть как у нас.

[Вот таблица](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html)

Comment: @VladD, @avp, я обновил свой вопрос примером. Давайте предположим, что интересен только русский алфавит. Сейчас для меня вопрос в том, как по двум байтам символа вытащить его 16-ричный код так, чтобы он совпадал с соответствующим кодом из таблицы Unicode, и не был перевёрнутым (как у меня сейчас). Я явно что-то путаю и буду рад вразумляющим советам.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, я выложил пару файлов [ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL) и [ucsutf.c](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW), которыми пользуюсь. 

Там есть функция utf8_to_ucs (const char \*utf, int \*step, int \*err), которая возвращает ucs.

Кстати, она не очень эффективна (как мне кажется), может как раз сейчас ее и перепишу.

--

А Ваш пример, я что-то не понимаю. Если в `bytes[]` у Вас исходный utf-8, то в `bytes[i]` закодированы старшие 5, в `bytes[i + 1]` младшие 6 бит 11-битного значения юникода русской буквы (и short тут вообще не при чем).

Comment: > А Ваш пример, я что-то не понимаю. Если в bytes[] у Вас исходный utf-8, то в bytes[i] закодированы старшие 5, в bytes[i + 1] младшие 6 бит 11-битного значения юникода русской буквы (и short тут вообще не при чем).

А, можете, пожалуйста, подсказать/показать, как мне изменить мой пример, чтобы можно было получить 16-ричный код этих двух байт (unsigned short - это по незнанию). Я пытаюсь обойтись без конвертации в ucs - или нельзя обойтись никак?

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich: кстати, проверка `'A' <= currentByte && currentByte <= 'z'` не вполне верна: между маленькими и большими буквами ещё есть небуквенные символы.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Я пытался эту часть "проскочить" побыстрее, и внимательно не поглядел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[@Stanislaw Pankevich](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich)](/users/10139/stanislaw-pankevich), простое начало

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char utf8len[256] = { 
  // len = utf8len[c] & 0x7  cont = utf8len[c] & 0x8 
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 0  - 15
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 16 - 31
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 32 - 47
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 48 - 63
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 64 - 79
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 80 - 95
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 96 - 111
  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, // 112 - 127

  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, // 80 - 8f
  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, // 90 - 9f
  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, // a0 - af
  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8, // b0 - bf

  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, // c0 - cf
  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, // d0 - df

  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3, // e0 - ef

  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  // f0 - f7

  5,  5,  5,  5,  // f8, f9, fa, fb

  6,  6,  // fc, fd

  0,  0   // fe, ff 
};

#define UTF8LEN(c) (utf8len[(unsigned char)(c)] & 0x7)
#define UTF8CONT(c) (utf8len[(unsigned char)(c)] & 0x8)

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *s = "Б№1АГД";

  while (*s) {
    int ucode;

    printf ("[%s] %d\n", s, UTF8LEN(*s));
    if ((UTF8LEN(*s) == 2) && UTF8CONT(s[1])) {
      ucode = ((*s & 0x1f) << 6) | (s[1] & 0x3f);
      printf ("ucode = 0x%x\n", ucode);
      s++;
    }
    s++;
  }

}
```

все основано на таблице длин utf-8 символов, определяемой по первому байту и проверке, что следующие байты в  этом utf-8 символе должны начинаться с 0x80

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc utf.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
[Б№1АГД] 2
ucode = 0x411
[№1АГД] 3
[��1АГД] 0
[�1АГД] 0
[1АГД] 1
[АГД] 2
ucode = 0x410
[ГД] 2
ucode = 0x413
[Д] 2
ucode = 0x414
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Я не проверяю здесь ascii и печатаю только коды русских (точнее любых 2-х байтных) символов.

Можно добавить несколько полезных макросов и получить

```
#define UTF8LEN(c) (utf8len[(unsigned char)(c)] & 0x7)
#define UTF8CONT(c) (utf8len[(unsigned char)(c)] & 0x8)

#define RUSUCODE(s) ({ char *_s = (s); \
      (((*_s & 0x1f) << 6) | (_s[1] & 0x3f)); })
#define ISRUSUC(c) ( { int _uc = (c); \
      ((0x410 <= _uc && _uc <= 0x44f) || _uc == 0x401 || _uc == 0x451); })
#define ISRUS(s) (ISRUSUC(RUSUCODE(s)))

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *rus = "АяёЁ";
  int Uaz = RUSUCODE(rus), 
    Lya = RUSUCODE(rus + 2), 
    Ujo = RUSUCODE(rus + 6), 
    Ljo = RUSUCODE(rus + 4);

  printf ("А 0x%x   я 0x%x   ё 0x%x   Ё 0x%x\n",
          Uaz, Lya, Ljo, Ujo);

  char *s = "Б№1АГД";

  while (*s) {
    int ucode;

    printf ("[%s] %d\n", s, UTF8LEN(*s));
    if ((UTF8LEN(*s) == 2) && UTF8CONT(s[1])) {
      ucode = RUSUCODE(s);
      printf ("ucode = 0x%x %s ", ucode, ISRUS(s) ? "Да" : "No");
      if (ISRUSUC(ucode))
        puts("rus letter");
      else
        puts(" ???");
      s++;
    }
    s++;
  }

}
```

Но, лучше сразу ориентироваться на обработку любых utf-8 символов.

(Как говорил мой знакомый автомеханик -- "делать надо хорошо, фигово само получится").

На самом деле, получив длину utf-8 символа из UTF8LEN() можно сразу увеличить s на нее (или на 1, сообщив об ошибке, если длина нулевая).

Хотя, я думаю, тут уже все и так понятно.

Comment: Ух ты! Мне нужно время, чтобы это всё пропустить через себя)) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Я всё-таки попробовал переворачивать местами байты у двухбайтных символов с кастом их в 2-байтовый unsigned char, и оказалось, что все диапазоны согласно [таблице hex-кодов](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=1024) прекрасно удаётся задавать и проверять для русскоязычных символов. Но оказалось, что Ваше решение с переводом в ucs работает немного быстрее: 

> ucode = ((*s & 0x1f) << 6) | (s[1] & 0x3f);

Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Перевести в `wchar_t` и использовать [`iswalpha`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/iswalpha.html)? Определяет любые буквы, не только русские/английские.

(В C++ есть ещё [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha) с локалью в качестве параметра, есть ли такое в чистом C?)

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ. Я пытаюсь разобраться, как сделать это вручную чисто через коды символов. Это частично упражнение, частично вспомогательный код для одного тестового задания, которое я хочу выполнить.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @avp невероятно крут, но все-таки надежнее использовать библиотеки:

- glib — довольно тяжелая, но полезная библиотека с кучей всего, в том числе работой с Юникодом, популярна в Linux, ибо служит основой для GNOME.
- icu — специальная библиотека конкретно про Юникод, используется например Apple под капотом `NSString`.

Comment: ICU, кстати, наверное единственное на текущий момент решение, претендующее на полноту.