# Как вычислить ucs-код для для однобайтового символа при работе с utf-8?

Tags: utf-8, c++

Вычислить код ucs для двухбайтового символа можно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299930#300040) (решение @avp). Что мне делать, если нужно вычислить код однобайтовых символов? Для моей задачи требуется определить, является ли символ английского или русского алфавита буквой. С русским всё понятно (как известно, кириллица кодируется двумя байтами). Как быть с ascii-символами?

Comment: Они кодируются одним байтом, разумеется.

Comment: Да, это очевидно. Проблема в вычислении самого UCS кода. Посмотрите пример для вычисления USC кода для символов, кодирующихся двумя байтами.Вот эта строчка:

ucode = ((*s & 0x1f) << 6) | (s[1] & 0x3f);

Ссылка на это решение дана в самом вопросе.

Comment: @milkyway_: `ucode = *s`?

Comment: @VladD Хм, вероятно, что так. Спасибо!

Comment: @milkyway_: может, @avp захочет что-то добавить?

---
Заметьте, что однобайтные символы — это лишь первая половина таблицы ASCII (`0x00..0x7f`). Символы, начиная с `0x80` — двухбайтные, и для них нужно использовать приведённый вами код. (До тех пор, пока не дойдёте до трёхбайтных и более.)

Comment: @VladD да, спасибо большое за ответы. Я предполагаю вычислять ucs-код простым ветвлением вроде

if (UTF8LEN(*chr)==1) { //for 1-byte encoded symbol
 ucsCode = *chr;
    }
    else if ((UTF8LEN(*chr) == 2) && UTF8CONT(chr[1])) { //for 2-bytes encoded symbol
        int ucsCode = ((chr[0] & 0x1f) << 6) | (chr[1] & 0x3f);
    }

и так далее.
Однако, к сожалению, я не могу разобраться с тем, как работает само преобразование в UCS: 
int ucsCode = ((chr[0] & 0x1f) << 6) | (chr[1] & 0x3f);

Работает оно корректно, это проверено. Но алгоритм остался непонятен. Может быть, @avp пояснит...

Comment: @milkyway_: Тут как раз всё понятно. Согласно [таблице](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), для двухбайтной кодировки значащие биты есть младшие 5 бит первого, и младшие 6 второго байта. Младшие 6 бит второго байта мы берём как есть (`s[1] & 0x3f`, `0x3f = 0011 1111` с двоичном смысле). Из первого байта выделяем 5 бит (`chr[0] & 0x1f`, `0x1f = 0001 1111`), сдвигаем их на 6 бит влево (эти биты возьмутся из 2-го байта) и соединяем (`|`).

Comment: @VladD спасибо огромное! теперь всё встало на свои места.

update. @VladD, посмотрите, пожалуйста, следующую функцию, преобразующую utf-8 в ucs-2: [link](http://www.lemoda.net/c/utf8-to-ucs2/index.html). Алгоритм вроде понятный, что что нужно указывать в качестве второго параметра?

Comment: @milkyway_: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 5):

Лимит комментариев вышел — могу лишь добавить ответ.

---

[[@milkyway_](/users/19447/milkyway_)](/users/19447/milkyway_): Смотрите. Вы заводите указатель на `char`, и передаёте *указатель* на этот указатель вторым параметром. Инициализировать сам указатель не надо. Имея указатель на ваш указатель, процедура может изменить его. (Это стандартный метод возвращения значений из функции в C.)

Согласно описанию, после возвращения из процедуры этот самый указатель будет указывать на первый неразобранный байт входной строки (то есть, на начало *следующего* UTF8-символа).

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем подвох. Ведь в то же самое число декодируются, разве нет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это по сути комментарий. Ответ на самом деле в первых комментариях к вопросу. В 2014 году движок Хэшкода не давал делать более четырёх комментариев, и приходилось использовать ответы. А в этом комментарии/ответе обсуждается по сути возможная модификация кода avp. То есть это ответ на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321386/321470#comment321428_321386

Comment: @VladD вы дали ссылку сюда же)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Хм, а у меня FF открывает на комментарии от «19 май '14 в 18:27»

Comment: @VladD а, я с мобильного читаю, тут ссылки на комментарии не обрабатываются. Но я вас понял )

Comment: @VladD про преимущества кодировок: 8 компактнее, совместима с ASCII и старыми программами. Код с UCS-2 может притворяться кодом с 16, но не 8. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: ну, компактнее она только в аглоцентричном мире, боюсь, так что не факт. Совместимость с ASCII тоже не большой плюс, примерно такой же, как совместимость UTF-16 с UCS-2. По факту мне кажется, что правильно обрабатывающий UTF-16 код должен быть немного _проще_, чем код, правильно обрабатывающий UTF-8 (но это, возможно, ощущения заядлого подвиндушника).

Comment: Ещё testability кода с 16 хуже: в наших текстах редко встречаются символы не из BMP, так что variable-length часть кода редко выполняется.

Comment: @VladD страница японской Википедии, насколько я помню, примерно одинаково весит в обеих кодировках, потому что html весь из первых 127 символов)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ага, вот testability — это да. Мне до сих пор в практике не попадались символы вне BMP.