# возврат функции strlen увеличивает значение в 2 раза при русской раскладке

Tags: c, strlen

```
struct namect {
   char fname[20];
   char lname[20];
   int letters;
};

void getinfo(struct namect *);
void makeinfo(struct namect *);
void showinfo(const struct namect *);

int main(void) {
   struct namect person;

   getinfo(&person);
   makeinfo(&person);
   showinfo(&person);

   return 0;
}
void getinfo(struct namect *pst) {
   printf("введите свое имя: \n");
   gets(pst->fname);
   printf("введите свою фамилию: \n");
   gets(pst->lname);
}
void makeinfo(struct namect * pst) {
   pst->letters = strlen(pst->fname) + strlen(pst->lname);
}
void showinfo(const struct namect *pst) {
   printf("%s %s, ваше имя и фамилия содержат %d букв.\n", pst->fname, pst->lname, pst->letters);
}
```

вывод 1:

> евгений малкин, ваше имя и фамилия содержат 26 букв.

вывод 2:

> sidney crosby, ваше имя и фамилия содержат 12 букв.

почему не правильно подсчитывает при русской раскладке?

Comment: strlen возвращает длину в байтах, а не в символах. А русские символы в кодировке UTF-8 длиной два байта. если нужно работать с символами, копайте в сторону обработки UTF8

Comment: смотрите wcslen

Comment: Проблема в том, что в C `char*` — массив байт, а не строка, что бы вам не говорили. Строкового типа в C нету. Так что вам придётся надеяться на библиотеки типа ICU или писать свой разбор Unicode руками (то ещё удовольствие).

Comment: Это "то ещё удовольствие" разбирали тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/299862/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-utf8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB-%D0%B2-char-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5

Comment: @Mike, А если это не Linux? Тогда там может быть UTF-16. Правильный подход здесь -- обрабатывать локаль (*LC_CTYPE*) и перекодировать во внутреннее представление (часто используют *UCS2-BE*), где длина *в символах* считается просто *размер строки в байтах / 2* (возможно с поправкой на *BOM*). Посмотрите исходники LibreOffice, например.

Comment: @0andriy Там точно UTF-8 потому что автор вопроса говорит, что "неправильно считает" только для русских, значит английские у него однобайтные

Comment: @Mike, прочитайте ещё раз, что я написал. Программу можно запустить с *LC_CTYPE* каким-угодно, тогда вообще всё к чертям полетит. Так не пишут код.

Comment: @Mike, Если хотите работать с юникодом лучше вообще забудьте все что вы знали о работе со строками на си :-) . Стандартная функция strlen всегда будет возвращать размер строки в байтах. Есть много сторонних библиотек для работы с юникодом лучше воспользуйтесь одной из них, libunistring например.

Comment: @rst256 А это вы к чему сказали, я вроде то же говорил, что strlen в байтах ... И я прекрасно знаю как работать с юникодом даже без библиотек https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474720/194569

Answer (score 0):

Если до зареза нужно посчитать длину строки в символах, то можно с помощью функции *iconv* преобразовать строку в любую однобайтовую кирилическую кодировку (cp1251, КОИ-8Р...) и потом вызвать *strlen*.